# How to use ng-model as element rather than attribute?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I want to use ng-model directive as element  rather than as attribute inside  tag,is there any way to do it?

well I've already designed my webpage in html and javascript and I want to include it in angularJS using "ng-include". So rather than adding attribute like,

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name='rejectedPartsConfirmtodothis' ng-model="reject">
```

I want to put it in the format like, (as said in angulaJS documentation )

```
<ng-model>
<input --->
</ng-model>
```

but this is not working, any idea how can I make it work?

Comment: what did you want to do ?

Comment: This is just not possible right now with current angular version.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the content of the [page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

Usage

> as element: (This directive can be used as custom element, but be aware of [IE restrictions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)).
>
> ```
> <ng-model>
> ...
> </ng-model>
> ```

Comment: @GSURENDARTHINA As you the timing of answer. Both are answered at same time.

I'm not duplicating the answer.

Comment: Oh., okey! just asked, if it meant something here. I'm just getting used to sof. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

according to v1.5 official documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

> Usage
>
> as element: (This directive can be used as custom element, but be aware of IE restrictions).
>
> ```
> <ng-model>
> ...
> </ng-model>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I dont really think there would be a use case where you would really need to do this...instead try some alternative but use ng-model as an attribute as ng-model is a pre-defined directive given by angularjs...

Answer (score 0):

You can build a new directive but you cannot modify ng-model to work as an element.